# javascript json [object text]

Tags: javascript, json

After taking json input and parsing it, I found that applying the text to an html tag, I get `[object text]`. Is there something I am missing, or is there some way to actually get the text out of the object that I seem to have for gotten about. I have included the code mostly for posterity.

```
function updateName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var text = document.createTextNode(sceneData.scene[curLoc].name);
    name.innerHTML = text;
}
```

and my data looks something like this:

```
sceneData = {'a':1, 's':1,
             'scene':[{'name':'Joe', 'line':'Hey, boss!'},
                      {'name':'Josh', 'line':'Morning, Joe!'}
            ]}
```

Comment: `name.innerHTML = sceneData.scene[curLoc].name;` instead. comment out the `// var text = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are setting [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which sets the string, instead you should use [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), as:

```
function updateName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var text = document.createTextNode(sceneData.scene[curLoc].name);
    name.appendChild(text);
}
```

or better directly set the html, as:

```
function updateName() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    name.innerHTML = sceneData.scene[curLoc].name;
}
```